# How to change Project appearance order in a solution in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have lots of projects in my solution which are sorted alphabetically. However, I want to arrange their appearance order for myself(PS: not build order). Is there any option to change project appearance order in VS 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group related projects together using solution folders

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6c756s6(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I want to know how can change the order of Project appearance, link of msdn not says this.

Comment: You can't unless you rename your projects. Projects inside solution folders are sorted alphabetically.